# Regex strange behavior

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to create a C#/WPF Parser. I have a good overall understanding of regular expressions since this is not my first parser (and will probably not be my last)

However, right now I have a very strange behavior. Here is what I am trying to parse (note: actual data removed, I just made a string following the same structure as mine):

> aaaaa bbbbb  50 c  blabla

My application would receive lines I just want to split and recognize. The number of spaces is, for some reason, variable (one between aaaa and bbbb, two between bbbb and 50... ).
(Note before people tell me: I won't use string.Split(). Because I have a LOT of different lines structures and I should always get the same data out of it. Just splitting it would make me unable to recognize what every part means)

My current test regexp is kinda simple:

```
(\S*)[\s*](\S*)[\s*](\S*)[\s*](p|c)(.*)
```

And now, here is what happens. When there is only one space betweet bbbbb and 50, the regex parses correctly (note: I use http://www.myregextester.com/index.php to test my regex )

```
$matches Array:
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => aaaaa bbbbb 50 c  blabla
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => aaaaa
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => bbbbb
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 50
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => c
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] =>   blabla
        )

)
```

If there are **two spaces** between bbbb and 50, here is what happens:

```
$matches Array:
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => bbbbb  50 c blabla
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => bbbbb
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 50
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => c
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  blabla
        )

)
```

Now I know I can easily remove the unwanted spaces from the line (which is what I currently do). I am anyway eager to understand what have I missed there: Why would this happen when I add one extra space, which should be recognized with one of the [\s*] I've added?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[\s*]` is not doing what you're expecting. The square brackets denote a character group, meaning that it will match a character that is either a `\s` (a space) or a **literal ***.

Simply drop those brackets to get the intended behaviour: match `\s` (a space) 0 or more times:

```
(\S*)\s*(\S*)\s*(\S*)\s*(p|c)(.*)
```

EDIT: Jesse's remark is also valuable: unless some groups are truly optional, you probably want to use `+` instead of `*` quantifiers.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know I couldn't use * in square brackets. As for the stars, there surely are way too much for now (although some groups are optional), I am going to use + as much as possible indeed

Comment: @Damascus What you should take away here is that the syntax of a regular expression is quite strict. Those square brackets have a very distinct meaning and you can't just swap them out whenever you like. It makes very much sense that `*` shouldn't do anything special when placed *inside* a character group, since a character group on its own will only ever match *one* character.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever I see stars in regex's, I cringe. Star matches zero or more, and can really trip you up! Replace all instances of `*` with `+` and try again. Unless, of course, some of those groupings are indeed optional.

EDIT: The other answers very correctly note that you were using a character group, but my point still stands: watch out for `*`!

Comment: You're absolutely right. I started with * because I was not sur if some groups were optional or not and I quickly got caught in the * vortex! I'll leave * only for the optional groups, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace `[\s*]` with `\s+`.

`[\s*]` means "Either one whitespace character, or one asterisk".

`\s+` means "One or more whitespace characters", which is what you want.

[Character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) are something so many people get wrong.

Answer (score -2):

[\s*] has a different meaning because it is inside the brackets[\s]+ would exhibit the behavior you desire or [\s]{1,} this expression will match whitespace characters 1 or more times.You also need to remember that depending on what function you are using you may need to enable the 'g' flag which is the global flag to enable your Regular Expressions to match all occurrences of the pattern you wish to parse otherwise it may only parse the first match. Brackets negate most character classes and turn most modifiers into literals except for a few exceptions visit MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions review your knowledge about how Regular Expressions behave inside brackets or PHP API on Regular Expressions http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php